# I am using BottomNavigationBar to navigate to diff SliverList. I observe that It does not retain to the last row that I scrolled. How can I fix this?

Tags: dart, flutter

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [Profile(), ServiceRequestList()];
  void _onTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: _children[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: _onTap,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text('Profile'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
              title: Text('Service'),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I am using BottomNavigationBar to navigate to diff SliverList. I observe that It does not retain to the last row that I scrolled. How can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageStorageKey is what you are looking for!

Within your Profile page and ServiceRequestList page's SliverList widget, set a unique page storage key like the following:

```
SliverList(
  key: PageStorageKey("somethingUnique"),
)
```

PageStorageKey works with any widget that has a scrolling region.